# SQL update query for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update 1000 rows

**This is my table:**

```
ID, name, keywords
1, foo, NULL
```

**I need to update like this:**

```
ID, name, keywords
1, "foo", "free foo, how  to foo free, download free foo"
1, "line", "free line, how  to line free, download line foo"
```

Comment: no, you need to change your DB structure! Never store multiple values in one column.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Joe Yeah just wanted to ask the same. This is just:"Keeping it short and let other people solve everything for me

Comment: RTM...? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is mytable you can do this:

```
update mytable set keywords = concat('free ',mytable.name,'how to ',mytable.name,', download free ',mytable.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with an update query like this where you concatenate the name into the keyword string.

```
update mytable set keywords=concat("free " , name , ", how to " , name , " free, download free", name);
```